# docker-compose gives error: no such service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Im trying to deploy with docker compose an app; mi yml is:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - 'dbdata:/data/db'
    container_name: database
  server:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '2000:2000'
    depends_on:
      - db    
    container_name: api
    links:
      - database
  frontend:
    build: ./client
    restart: always    
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - server    
    container_name: client
    links:
      - api                
volumes: 
  dbdata:
```

When i docker compose up -d this in my PC it works correctly, but when i do the same thing in a oracle linux 8.6 fedora; seems like is working fine until came to the lines:

```
Network soccer_default  Created                                                                                                                                                    
no such service: database
```

And stop the process. Is something related with the machine or docker version?

Comment: The service name is `db`, not `database`.

Comment: And, if you want to *refer* to it as `database` within `server`, you use `"db:database"`. Frontend link to `api` has the same issue BTW.

Comment: Easier solution is to just delete the `links:` sections entirely, incorrect name and all: it's an obsolete option from first-generation Docker networking and it's not necessary any more.  You can also safely remove `container_name:` without affecting anything.